# How to create full width table with sticky table header

Tags: html, css

I want to create a full-width table with a sticky table header that allows horizontal scrolling. I have accomplished this by setting a fixed size using `max-height` to the `.table-wrapper` class (for example, `.table-wrapper {max-height: 500px;}`). (as it creates multiple scroll in the page and it's not user friendly) However, I'm seeking an alternative method that doesn't rely on `max-height`. Is there another way to achieve this?

Please see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vahidrajaei/m43bn0wd/22/)

```css
.screen {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.table-wrapper {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* Make the table container scrollable */

.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ensure the container takes up full width */
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Fix the table header at the top */

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  /* Optional: Add background color to make it distinct */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Optional: Ensure it stays on top of other elements */
}


/* Ensure the table fills the width of its container */

table {
  width: auto;
  /* Make the table size dynamically based on content */
  min-width: 100%;
  /* Ensure the table takes up at least full width of container */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Optional: Collapse border spacing */
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* Ensure equal column widths */
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  /* Optional: Adjust cell padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Optional: Add borders to cells */
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Fixed Table Header with Horizontal Scrolling</title>
<div class="screen table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <!-- Add more header columns as needed -->
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
          <th>Column 9</th>
          <th>Column 10</th>
          <th>Column 11</th>
          <th>Column 12</th>
          <!-- More column headers -->
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Row 1</th>
          <th>Row 2</th>
          <th>Row 3</th>
          <th>Row 4</th>
          <th>Row 5</th>
          <th>Row 6</th>
          <th>Row 7</th>
          <th>Row 8</th>
          <th>Row 9</th>
          <th>Row 10</th>
          <th>Row 11</th>
          <th>Row 12</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say `max-height` in your question but your code has `max-width`.

Comment: @JosephWebber. Please read the question carefully. The `max-width` in the code is correct as the width is fixed. one way to achieve this is setting a max-width which I don't want to use it.

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't use max-height?

Comment: @Stickers It creates multiple scroll in the page and the stackholders don't like it.

Comment: @Stickers. I've mentioned. Scroll only horizontally <--->

Answer (score 0):

For others who may find it useful, I initially encountered difficulties achieving this without resorting to using `max-width`. However, I successfully implemented the solution by **toggling the `table-wrapper` class**. You can now add the `table-wrapper` class to the tables that require it, while leaving other table styles unchanged. This approach ensures that we maintain the integrity of other table styles.